# making logical partitions after installing win 7

Tags: partitioning

I have already installed win 7 in my primary partition (30GB). Now I want to make logical partitions in the rest of the disk space (566GB) but I don't want to use partition wizard. Advice will be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Using Disk Manager is the easiest way.

However you can do it from a command prompt with the DISKPART utility.

```
DISKPART> select disk 0
DISKPART> list partition
DISKPART> create partition extended
DISKPART> create partition logical
```

The last two commands create an extended partition in which you will put the logicals, and the logical partition itself.  Choose the sizes you need.